# Update alternatives java for my user

Tags: java, sudo, configuration, users, update-alternatives

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with multiple java versions. I'm trying to change the current java version for my user with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

I change to the right one but when I do:

```
java -version
```

I still receive the old one. When I do:

```
sudo java -version
```

I receive the new one.

I need the new java version to be set for my user (without `sudo`).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `update-alternatives` can only be set globally.

If you want to use a different version of java at any time, specify the full path on the command line or in the script, or if this is for applications that will check `JAVA_HOME`, set `JAVA_HOME` at the end of your `~/.profile`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/version/I/want
```

or export the above in the shell to use only in the current session

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my `JAVA_HOME` variable
Had to add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=path/to/correct/version
```

then everything worked.

Comment: When I execute `echo $JAVA_HOME` is empty. How do I update my java version

Comment: I **guess**: from playing with different versions this variable was already set (and pointed to the wrong version).